# An idiom meaning "sticking fingers in your ears does not change the fact"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom which means sticking fingers in your ears does not change the fact; the fact remains so, even if you don't listen to the one who is mentioning it.

Comment: Not an idiom, exactly, but perhaps you can make a kind of reversal of one: “An ignored pot always keeps boiling” or something to that effect.

Comment: *You can't wish it away*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Perhaps "A pot ignored boils on." Has a nice ring to it.

Comment: @called2voyage, I like ‘boils on’ better, yes. The parallelism with ‘a watched pot never boils’ is lost if you switch the word order like that, though. ‘An ignored pot always boils on’ would work. Or perhaps (changing the verb) ‘an ignored pot never cools’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was thinking of making it more of a (non-rhyming) couplet: "A watched pot never boils,/ but a pot ignored boils on." Many idiomatic English phrases exist in this form because it is easier to remember something that has a rhythm to it. That's why I omitted the parallelism.

Comment: "Reality is that which, when you stop believing in it, doesn't go away." - Philip K Dick

Comment: "If nothing else works, a total pig-headed unwillingness to look facts in the face will see us through" - General Melchett

Comment: You are just deceiving yourself.

Comment: Reminded me of "Sticking feathers up your butt does not make you a chicken" :)

Comment: "How many times can a man turn his head, and pretend that he just doesn't see?"

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> [Don't bury your head in the sand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+head+in+the+sand)
>    Fig. to ignore or hide from obvious signs of danger. (Alludes to an ostrich, which is believed incorrectly to hide its head in a hole in the ground when it sees danger.)
>    *"Stop burying your head in the sand. Look at the statistics on smoking and cancer."*

[This 1760 dictionary](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vnsCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT395&dq=%22head%20in%20the%20sand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KfnLUqy3FbGS7AbZoICQDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22head%20in%20the%20sand%22&f=false) says the general concept goes back to at least [Pliny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliny_the_Elder) in the first century...

> *...it will thrust its head into the bushes, and remain there as if her whole body was well concealed. Again, it is said that the ostrich is naturally deaf, which does not a little contribute to her stupidity.*

---

There's also the closely-related saying...

> [If wishes were horses, beggars would ride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_wishes_were_horses,_beggars_would_ride)

...which essentially means *"Wishful thinking obviously **doesn't** change things in the real world"*

Answer (score 22):

You can break the thermometer but you can't change the weather.

Comment: Never heard this before but I kinda like it. Google doesn't know it either so I'm guessing you either made it up or translated it from another language.

Comment: I can't find the whole expression but "can't change the weather" does seem to be idiomatic.

Comment: That would seem to violate the Butterfly Effect Law  :-)

Comment: I’ve mainly heard versions of this from the days when barometers (aka “weather-glasses”), not thermometers, where the instrument in question.  From [the original (fantastic and under-appreciated) Casino Royale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_Royale_(1967_film)): “You can break the bloody glass, but you can’t hold back the weather.”

Comment: @PLL Thanks, that definitely gives some precedence to this phrase (in some form).

Answer (score 10):

**Facts are stubborn things.**
- [John Adams](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_Adams)

Perhaps a more subtle approach, although not directly addressing the "fingers in the ears" part.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, TimH. We appreciate your input. This is more of a "comment" than an answer, but once you have earned enough [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you will be able to comment, which can include opinions and additional information, such as this interesting fact. :)

Comment: I often wonder where does a comment end and an answer start? According to the input help a comment can have up to 600 characters. In doubt i favor a short answer over a comment because an answers can have his own comments and avoids multiple comments with different subjects attached to the same question.

Comment: Thanks, @Susan! I will try to keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Along the lines of FumbleFingers second offer, the phrase **[wish away](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wish+away)** is found in US usage.

> **wish someone or something away**
>
> to wish that someone or something would go away.
>
> *You can't just wish him away. You'll have to ask him to leave!*
>
> *Don't try to wish away the difficulties of your life.*

Answer (score 5):

More of an aphorism than an idiom, this frequently quoted statement from Moynihan:
"Everyone is entitled to his own opinion, but not his own facts".

Answer (score 4):

A fact ignored remains a fact.

Truth ignored remains the truth.

Conversely:

A lie believed (or accepted) is still a lie.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't refer to ears or any other part of the anatomy, but people who behave like this *'never let a fact get in the way of an opinion'*, an expression I have had occasion to use far too frequently for my liking...

Comment: I have heard ‘‘Don’t bother me with facts; I’ve made up my mind.’’

Comment: @Scott Really? I'm amazed! Most people I've known who  definitely don't want to hear facts nor change their opinion  never have the courage to say it that clearly...

Answer (score 2):

A classic, and somewhat snide, idiom which captures this situation is

### *And yet it moves...*

This is the English translation of a famous quote by Galileo:

> ***E pur si muove*** (or *Eppur si muove*)

Which he spoke (one imagines *sotto voce*) after [his imprisonment for promulgating the heresy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair) that the Earth orbits the Sun, in contradiction to the Church's (then) position that the Earth (and its people) was placed at the very center of the universe by God Himself.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=And_yet_it_moves&oldid=681874036):

> In this context, the implication of the phrase is: despite this recantation, the Church's proclamations to the contrary, or any other conviction or doctrine of men, the Earth does, in fact, move [around the sun, and not vice versa]. As such, the phrase is used today as a sort of pithy retort implying that "it doesn't matter what you believe; these are the facts".